# How to persistent storage in angularjs/Phonegap (ios, android, chrome)

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, google-chrome, cordova

I am writing an angularjs app that I want to deploy to mobile (iOS and Android) and test in Google Chrome (with Ripple).
I can't figure out how to store data persistent and local.

LocalStorage is not supported as permanent storage by iOS (seriously Apple?)
WebSQL is deprecated

How can I cross device store data permanently?

Edit: I only want to save an auth token.

Comment: why do you think that WebSQL is deprecated? I don't see anything about deprecating it in Cordova documentation, even in new 3.4.0. I suppose you still can save permanent data in database or in files without problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haven't used Cordova yet so let me know if this is wrong and I'll remove it:

http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.5.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html

appears they have provided an abstraction layer for storage.  I wasn't aware until just now that Cordova relies on the built in WebView or UI whatever in iOS to work... bit of a bummer.